# How to assign column variable 'Date' with date value from file name (Pandas)

Tags: pandas

I have the following file name....

```
Filename = ('../BSOS Supplier Sales (01289), 02.04.2018 - 08.04.2018 (X).xlsx')
```

I want to 
1) Read the file into a df and 
2) assign a new Column variable "Date" with the date captured in the above filename (02.04.2018 - 08.04.2018

How can this be done using pd.read_excel(Filename)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the content to a DataFrame

```
df = pd.read_excel(Filename)
```

Now extract the date with a regular expression

```
import re
date = re.compile(r'([\.\d]+ - [\.\d]+)').search(Filename).groups()[0]
```

And add to the DataFrame a new column with it

```
df['Date'] = date
```